# Why won't my router open these ports?

Tags: windows, networking, port-forwarding

I have a web service that I'm going to need to open ports for.

I've used my Verizon router to open the ports. The port-checker service I use checks for games, so I'm testing my ability to open ports using port 2302. Here are the settings I'm using for my router:

[image]

The port checker service at whatismyip.org shows this port to be closed. How do I open it, am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are the games hosted on a individual computer?

Comment: Yes, they are hosted from an individual computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forwarding the ports rather than just opening them.

Comment: What does that look like?

Comment: @Chromium: Your screenshot shows that they're already forwarded; I believe people are being confused by you having described them as "opened".

Comment: I understand. So if they're already forwarding, how do I test that?

Answer (score -1):

The port checker service is correct; the port is closed on 192.168.1.14. Try checking while the game is running.